# Swig -outdir option doesn't include the .so file

Tags: python, cmake, swig

I have a small project where I use the CMake system to create a Python module out of C++ files. In the CMakeLists.txt file I have Swig integrated as follows:

```
# only the Swig part here
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/../lib/Foo)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(swig/interface.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_source_files_properties(swig/interface.i SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall;-c++;-shadow")
swig_add_module(Foo python swig/interface.i code/foo.cpp)
swig_link_libraries(Foo foolib ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

My first question is why not both the Foo.py **and** the _Foo.so are created in the location specified by `CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR`? Only the .py file is created in that directory. Is this a bug of the CMake UseSWIG.cmake file? The .so file is still in the `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR` location. As a result, I can't load the module in Python if only the location `CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR` is in the `PYTHON_PATH` environment variable. So to solve this problem I could either:

1. Add the `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR` directory to the `PYTHON_PATH`.
2. Copy the .so file to `CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR` or create a symbolic link using the CMake system.
3. Don't set the `CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR` variable so that everything is created in the `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR` and add only this location to `PYTHON_PATH`.

But none of these seem to be the logic thing to do, for the `CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR` should be used to output both the .py and the .so files. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure *why* CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR does not affect the location of where the .so file gets generated.  However, I can tell you of a simpler and cleaner way of indicating where the .so file should get generated.

After your `swig_add_module(Foo ...)`, a CMake target called `_Foo` gets created.  You can then edit the target's properties and change where its library (.so file) gets generated - `set_target_properties(.. LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY <so_file_output_dir>)`.

---

So in your code, just add the `set_target_properties(..)` line shown below:

```
...
swig_add_module(Foo python swig/interface.i code/foo.cpp)
set_target_properties(_Foo PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR})
swig_link_libraries(Foo foolib ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
...
```

Comment: _Foo should be equivalent to ${SWIG_MODULE_Foo_REAL_NAME} if you want to be pedantic about it
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/UseSWIG.html